# dir="auto" works in firefox but not chrome

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, i18next

I'm making a webapp using Bootstrap 3 and the i18next library to support multiple languages.

When switching from LTR languages to RTL languages, in Firefox all of the words switch and align to the right, but in Chrome the words are translated, but don't align right and things like punctuation are on the wrong side.

Is there a reason the dir="auto" tag shouldn't work in Chrome to properly display RTL languages?

Comment: it seems as though this is a Bootstrap issue

Comment: This is actually a bug in Chrome. I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in Chrome and it is unrelated to Bootstrap 3.

It happens when your rtl text starts on a new line:

```
<p dir="auto">
الف    
</p>
```

However, if you put your text inline, then it works.

```
<p dir="auto">الف</p>
```

Somehow, Chrome sees the line return as the first strong character and decides to go left-to-right.  But when you have the text inline, the first strong character is recognized and rendered properly.

[Chromium Issue 477220](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=477220&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

Answer (score 0):

```
right: auto overrides right: 0

.dir_rtl #main_search_wrapper {
   right: auto;
   left: 0;
}
```

Comment: could you explain this? I'm new to CSS and was just using the Bootstrap CSS file.